# Python 2.7 formatting data for writing as csv

Tags: python, datetime, csv

I'm trying to write data into a CSV file. I have data from several sensors and time/date from a Real Time Clock.
The sensor data is fine but I'm going round in circles with formatting the RTC data. I've tried lots of things and read as many relevant posts as my ageing brain can handle.

The clock data is in val

```
#print "second =", val[0]
#print "minute =", val[1]
#print "hour =", val[2]
#print "day of week =", val[3]
#print "day of month =", val[4]
#print "month =", val[5]
#print "year =", val[6]
```

So for instance this prints time followed by date.

```
print "RTC Time is ", val[2], ":", val[1], ":", val[0]
print "RTC Date is ", val[4], "/", val[5], "/", "20",val[6]
```

The closest I've got to what I actually want is.

```
   import csv

   datetime = val[6],val[5],val[4],val[2],val[1],val[0]

   filecsv = open('tidelog.csv', 'a+') #writing to csv log file
   writer = csv.writer(filecsv,dialect='excel')
   stuff = [datetime, temp_inside, humidity, press, response]
   writer.writerow(stuff)
   filecsv.close()
```

The output csv looks like this

```
"(14, 3, 28, 15, 52, 37)",29,47,1005,2208
```

The date/time yy mm dd hh mm ss is inside the quotes

What I'm trying to get is the date time with hyphen separators in the first column like below.

```
14-3-28-15-52-37,29,47,1005,2208
```

Any help would be appreciated

Derek

Comment: `datetime.strftime` is your friend.

Comment: This `datetime = val[6],val[5],val[4],val[2],val[1],val[0]` implicitly creates a tuple. Try `>>> 1,2,3` in the interpreter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` with a hyphen like so:

```
>>> val
[37, 52, 15, 4, 28, 3, 14]
>>> '-'.join(str(x) for x in [val[6],val[5],val[4],val[2],val[1],val[0]])
'14-3-28-15-52-37'
```

Your method does not work because you are implicitly creating a tuple:

```
>>> 1,2,3
(1, 2, 3)
>>> val[6],val[5],val[4],val[2],val[1],val[0]
(14, 3, 28, 15, 52, 37)
```

---

*Edit*

As stated in the comments, you can use [reversed](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#reversed) on your list rather than index by index:

```
>>> list(reversed([1,2,3,4,5]))
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Might be a little easier to read if you used [reversed()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed)

Comment: I'll try to remember the reversed next time